# How do I set navigation transition between loaded Stacks of createBottomTabNavigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Im using react-navigation version 3.3.2 and the current transition between loaded stacks of screens is it will show up sliding from the bottom to the top.

```
import { createAppContainer, createBottomTabNavigator, createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: createStackNavigator({...screens}),
  Settings: createStackNavigator({...screens}),
}, { 
...
})

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(TabNavigator);
```

The first time I navigate from Home to Settings, the Settings screen shows up like reloading a website page.

The second time I navigate from Home to Settings, the Settings screen shows up sliding about 400ms from bottom to top (really unfriendly).

So how can I change it to transition like the first time or at least change the sliding time?

Comment: Updated 2023 Sep 4th!